# Error: could not get license agreement

Tags: macos, high-sierra, apfs

I have macOS Sierra installed and have an SSD and using the following command to avoid conversion to APFS

```
/Applications/Install\ macOS\ High\ Sierra.app/Contents/Resources/startosinstall --converttoapfs NO
```

but I get the following error:

> Error: could not get license agreement

Also if I add the parameter `--agreetolicense` I get the error

```
Helper tool crashed...
```

Anyone having similar issue knows how to tackle that situation or my Installer is corrupt? Anyhow, I am able to run the installer and accept the agreement but that would also automatically convert my file system to APFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the installer was indeed broken, when I ran it directly it would start downloading the setup from the internet without letting me know that it is downloading. Checked that with Activity Monitor > Sort Activities by the Network column. Also, double check the size of the .app file you get from someone. I copied the setup from local area network so something might have gone nuts.

> ^ These are some tips in such a case.

Copy the installer again or download it and the above commands (in the question) will work like a charm.